# applying user defined function on data frames in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am working on a dataframe

```
data = {'country': ['Belgium', 'France', 'Germany', 'Netherlands', 'United Kingdom'],
    'population': [11.3, 64.3, 81.3, 16.9, 64.9],
    'area': [30510, 671308, 357050, 41526, 244820],
    'capital': ['Brussels', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Amsterdam', 'London']}
```

countries = DataFrame(data, index=list('pqrst'))

Now I want to apply a function standardize to standardized numerical column only.I have defined this function as

```
def standardizing(s):

    t=s.apply(lambda x: (x-s.mean())/s.std())
    print t,'\n'
    print "New standardized mean     ",t.mean()
    print "New standardized deviation    ",t.std()
```

- I need to know how to subset dataframe basis on only numerical data.
- How to call function `standardizing` for each numerical column

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select_dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) function, and then loop through the columns of that data frame.

```
numeric_data = countries.select_dtypes(include=['number'])

for col_name in numeric_data:
    standardizing(numeric_data[col_name])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SeemaMudgil I know this is years later, but if you found the answer useful, why did't you mark it as the answer? This gives the person who answered the question some more reputation points.